# Match all lines in findstr.exe?

Tags: batch-file, findstr

How to specify expression to findstr.exe to let it match all lines? This is useful to get the line number for the content or check whether given file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match all lines.

```
findstr "^" "file.txt"
```

Comment: this works. I am wondering how to understand "^" in this command.

Comment: `^` means "Beginning of the line". See `findstr /?` It's a common way to get all (including empty) lines.